# Are IPv6 link-local addresses assigned by the kernel or by a userspace program

Tags: networking, kernel, network-interface, ipv6

When IPv6 is enabled for an interface, it will get a link-local address assigned automatically based on the MAC of the network interface.

But who assigns this address? Is it done in the kernel, or by some userspace program that also sets up the interface?

Ideally, I would also be interested in a link to the actual source code where it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [kernel](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/sys/netinet6/in6_ifattach.c?rev=1.99&content-type=text/plain) on OpenBSD via `in6_ifattach_linklocal`, as found by a `fgrep -rl fe80 /usr/src 2>/dev/null` search.